# browsing distinct Neo4j databases in the same machine

Tags: neo4j

I am experimenting with several Neo4j databases in my machine. The databases have been generated and populated from Java programs.
Now I would like to inspect them.

It seems that the recommended way is to open the web console so it points to a specific database by means of configuring the property:

`org.neo4j.server.database.location=<database location path>`

in the neo4j configuration file: `conf/neo4j-server.properties`

This if fine if I am only interested in one database. But it does not look like a good idea if I am switching often between databases or if I want to explore more than one at the same time.
Is it possible to configure distinct web consoles (maybe using distinct ports) so they refer to my distinct databases?

And is it possible to do this without installing several instances (binaries) of Neo4j in my machine and having to modify lots of configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  If you edit that same `conf/neo4j-server.properties` file you can change the `org.neo4j.server.webserver.port` and `org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port` values (I normally set the `https` port to one less than the `http` port).

Once you've done that you run `./bin/neo4j start` (make sure you shut down your Java app which is accessing the database first) to start the server on that port and then simply visit `http://localhost:<port>`

I'm not 100% sure if generating the database from Java will generate everything that you need for running a server.  If not you can download Neo4j from http://neo4j.com/download/, make multiple copies of it, and replace the `graph.db` folder with yours one (make sure you shut down any processes which are accessing those databases before copying the directory).  Also if you've downloaded a newer version you might need to set `allow_store_upgrade=true` (see: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-upgrading.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple Embedded Neo4j databases without installing separate binaries. You just need to be configure the different database path for each instance of the database.

Comment: how I can do this so I can have distinct web consoles open at the same time and pointing to them?

Comment: Sure. But my question is how to open web consoles on distinct databases so I can browse and inspect them at the same time.

Comment: have never tried to open multiple webconsoles but i guess with different ports you can. (Sorry for multiple edits and removal of last comment but somehow it's formatting was screwed up).